# Which character encoding is best for levenshtein and MySQL Match?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm kind of in a fix. I recently came to notice that my users are inputting international language characters when they search. It is completely screwing up my search algorithm in place. After reading my below problem, could you please suggest which *single-byte* character encoding would be the best to support searches in languages with script similar to English like french, german, spanish, etc.

**My Setup**

My search is a MySQL Match on a full-indexed Database and then a PHP Levenshtein to further filter out the rows.  MySQL databse is `ISO-8859-1` encoded and the search is `UTF-8` encoded (because, I heard that UTF-8 is a better charset which supports more international chracters.)

**MySQL Problem**

Being a 2 step process on searching. I wasn't able to get a definitive answer on how to approach this problem on which character encoding to set my database in.

As of now, the database is in `ISO-8859-1` encoding. For a `MATCH AGAINST` search on the DB,

1. I would like a query like `Amelie` to return rows with `Amélie` . That is, supporting cross language searches for a non-native keyboard.
2. For a native keyboard an input like `Amélie` should ofcourse return back `Amélie`. Just the vice versa of the above (it's only natural for a search to do that!)

The next part of the problem is applying levenshtein function to see the closeness of the text.

**Levenshtein Problem**

Let us assume that I've some how successfully returned `Amelie` for `Amélie` and similarly, `Amélie` for `Amelie`. Now, the next problem is that being a non-native speaker of french (yes, that's french) I would expect my levenshtein to give a distance of **1** because `é` is replaced with `e`.

Now, since my API is UTF-8 encoded. An input like `Amélie` from the user is converted by the API into a UTF-8 encoded string like `Am\u00e9lie` and then levenshtein on this is just a terrible thing to do. Because, I get the distance between them as 6. But in reality, I would expect them to be the same since they are the exact same thing!

```
$distance = levenshtein("Amu00e9lie","Amélie",1,1,1) //outputs 6
```

1. Complication 1 : Having said that, the immediate conclusion one could make is that the DB should have `Amélie` UTF-8 encoded to `Amu00e9lie` in which case the distance would be 0. (This suggests that I should probably go for single byte charset? In which case, what?)
2. Complication 2 : Unfortunately, that suggestion would not work, because then a search like `Amu00e9lie` on the DB wouldn't return the english version `Amuelie`.

**Summary**

I've tried to completely elaborate my problem. From this, The first priority is given to the DB. It should be encoded such that the 2 problems I listed in "MySQL Problem" are met and next, making sure that levenshtein holds for this charset in a "sensible" way as decribed above.

Also, the constraint that I'm faced with, is that I do not have  access to the root of MySQL. I don't think will matter much but just saying.

Answer (score 2):

First: the character encoding you are using (e.g, `"Am\u00e9lie"`) is not "UTF-8". It's ASCII, containing a Javascript escaped string. Performing any kind of search or comparison on these strings will be painful.

What you need to do is convert the table (ideally, all of your tables) to the MySQL `utf8mb4` (or, failing that, `utf8`) character encoding, and store Unicode strings natively in that table. Once you have done so, searches will "just work" -- that is, searching for `name = 'Amelie'` will find `'Amélie'`, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the insight

Comment: In other words, Levenshtein is _not_ part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. While running my tests yesterday, the DB seemed to work just fine with ISO-8859-1 encoding. I had to utf8_decode the API queries for matching the MySQL encoding and Levenshtein didnt't seem to have a problem with  ISO-8859-1 comparisions as well! I'm guessing, you're suggesting UTF-8 would be a better alternative?

Comment: ISO-8859-1 only supports a small set of international characters. Use UTF-8.